# Postgres Explain Plans Are DIfferent for same query with different value

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I have databases running Postgres 9.56 on heroku.
I'm running the following SQL with different parameter value, but getting very different results in the performance.

**Query 1**

```
SELECT COUNT(s), DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', t.departure)
 FROM tk_seat s
 LEFT JOIN tk_trip t ON t.trip_id = s.trip_id
 WHERE DATE_PART('year', t.departure)= '2017'
 AND t.trip_status = 'BOOKABLE'
```

> ```
>  AND t.route_id = '278'
> ```

```
 AND s.seat_status_type != 'NONE'
 AND s.operator_id = '15'
 GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', t.departure)
 ORDER BY DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', t.departure)
```

**Query 2**

```
SELECT COUNT(s), DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', t.departure)
 FROM tk_seat s
 LEFT JOIN tk_trip t ON t.trip_id = s.trip_id
 WHERE DATE_PART('year', t.departure)= '2017'
 AND t.trip_status = 'BOOKABLE'
```

> ```
>  AND t.route_id = '150'
> ```

```
 AND s.seat_status_type != 'NONE'
 AND s.operator_id = '15'
 GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', t.departure)
 ORDER BY DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', t.departure)
```

**Only Difference is t.route_id value.**

So, I tried running **explain** and give me very different result.

**For Query 1**

```
"GroupAggregate  (cost=279335.17..279335.19 rows=1 width=298)"
"  Group Key: (date_trunc('MONTH'::text, t.departure))"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=279335.17..279335.17 rows=1 width=298)"
"        Sort Key: (date_trunc('MONTH'::text, t.departure))"
"        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..279335.16 rows=1 width=298)"
"              Join Filter: (s.trip_id = t.trip_id)"
"              ->  Seq Scan on tk_trip t  (cost=0.00..5951.88 rows=1 width=12)"
"                    Filter: (((trip_status)::text = 'BOOKABLE'::text) AND (route_id = '278'::bigint) AND (date_part('year'::text, departure) = '2017'::double precision))"
"              ->  Seq Scan on tk_seat s  (cost=0.00..271738.35 rows=131594 width=298)"
"                    Filter: (((seat_status_type)::text <> 'NONE'::text) AND (operator_id = '15'::bigint))"
```

**For Query 2**

```
"Sort  (cost=278183.94..278183.95 rows=1 width=298)"
"  Sort Key: (date_trunc('MONTH'::text, t.departure))"
"  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=278183.92..278183.93 rows=1 width=298)"
"        Group Key: date_trunc('MONTH'::text, t.departure)"
"        ->  Hash Join  (cost=5951.97..278183.88 rows=7 width=298)"
"              Hash Cond: (s.trip_id = t.trip_id)"
"              ->  Seq Scan on tk_seat s  (cost=0.00..271738.35 rows=131594 width=298)"
"                    Filter: (((seat_status_type)::text <> 'NONE'::text) AND (operator_id = '15'::bigint))"
"              ->  Hash  (cost=5951.88..5951.88 rows=7 width=12)"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on tk_trip t  (cost=0.00..5951.88 rows=7 width=12)"
"                          Filter: (((trip_status)::text = 'BOOKABLE'::text) AND (route_id = '150'::bigint) AND (date_part('year'::text, departure) = '2017'::double precision))"
```

My question is why and how can i make it same? Because first Query give me very bad performance

**Query 1 Analyze**

```
"GroupAggregate  (cost=274051.28..274051.31 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=904682.606..904684.283 rows=7 loops=1)"
"  Group Key: (date_trunc('MONTH'::text, t.departure))"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=274051.28..274051.29 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=904682.432..904682.917 rows=13520 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: (date_trunc('MONTH'::text, t.departure))"
"        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1018kB"
"        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.42..274051.27 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=1133.925..904676.254 rows=13520 loops=1)"
"              Join Filter: (s.trip_id = t.trip_id)"
"              Rows Removed by Join Filter: 42505528"
"              ->  Index Scan using tk_trip_route_id_idx on tk_trip t  (cost=0.42..651.34 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.020..2.720 rows=338 loops=1)"
"                    Index Cond: (route_id = '278'::bigint)"
"                    Filter: (((trip_status)::text = 'BOOKABLE'::text) AND (date_part('year'::text, departure) = '2017'::double precision))"
"                    Rows Removed by Filter: 28"
"              ->  Seq Scan on tk_seat s  (cost=0.00..271715.83 rows=134728 width=8) (actual time=0.071..2662.102 rows=125796 loops=338)"
"                    Filter: (((seat_status_type)::text <> 'NONE'::text) AND (operator_id = '15'::bigint))"
"                    Rows Removed by Filter: 6782294"
"Planning time: 1.172 ms"
"Execution time: 904684.570 ms"
```

**Query 2 Analyze**

```
"Sort  (cost=275018.88..275018.89 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=2153.843..2153.843 rows=9 loops=1)"
"  Sort Key: (date_trunc('MONTH'::text, t.departure))"
"  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB"
"  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=275018.86..275018.87 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=2153.833..2153.834 rows=9 loops=1)"
"        Group Key: date_trunc('MONTH'::text, t.departure)"
"        ->  Hash Join  (cost=2797.67..275018.82 rows=7 width=8) (actual time=2.472..2147.093 rows=36565 loops=1)"
"              Hash Cond: (s.trip_id = t.trip_id)"
"              ->  Seq Scan on tk_seat s  (cost=0.00..271715.83 rows=134728 width=8) (actual time=0.127..2116.153 rows=125796 loops=1)"
"                    Filter: (((seat_status_type)::text <> 'NONE'::text) AND (operator_id = '15'::bigint))"
"                    Rows Removed by Filter: 6782294"
"              ->  Hash  (cost=2797.58..2797.58 rows=7 width=12) (actual time=1.853..1.853 rows=1430 loops=1)"
"                    Buckets: 2048 (originally 1024)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 78kB"
"                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tk_trip t  (cost=32.21..2797.58 rows=7 width=12) (actual time=0.176..1.559 rows=1430 loops=1)"
"                          Recheck Cond: (route_id = '150'::bigint)"
"                          Filter: (((trip_status)::text = 'BOOKABLE'::text) AND (date_part('year'::text, departure) = '2017'::double precision))"
"                          Rows Removed by Filter: 33"
"                          Heap Blocks: exact=333"
"                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on tk_trip_route_id_idx  (cost=0.00..32.21 rows=1572 width=0) (actual time=0.131..0.131 rows=1463 loops=1)"
"                                Index Cond: (route_id = '150'::bigint)"
"Planning time: 0.211 ms"
"Execution time: 2153.972 ms"
```

Comment: explain analyze please :). Did you analyzed those tables?

Comment: Unrelated, but: please use number literals for numbers and string literals for strings. `'15'` is a string, not a number in SQL

Comment: i did vacuum, analyze, full vacuum. but still give me same result.

Comment: explain analyze also same. first query take too much time

Comment: @user3464165 ok, but we will se how many records planner is expecting and how much he actually gets and what operation is time consuming

Comment: understood. i edit post with analyze result. pls help me understand. thanks

Comment: Don't try to force pgsql to use a particular plan, try to adjust the tuning parameters to get it to use the best plan for that particular query and its values. Look for things like mismatched row counts (expecting 1 and getting 38,000 for example) and look for ways to let the database know more about the data in it. stats target, random page cost, etc. The whole point behind postgresql's query planner is that you should never have to force it to use a certain plan, but teach it enough about your db and data that it gets it right.

Comment: Also use the site https://explain.depesz.com/ to upload your explain plans for analysis

Comment: Here's the explain interpreted by depesz: https://explain.depesz.com/s/mt9

It looks like it expects 1 row from the index scan in step 4 but is getting 338. That's a pretty big difference. Have you run analyze on this table etc?

Comment: Try turning up this value and running analyze again: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/runtime-config-query.html#GUC-DEFAULT-STATISTICS-TARGET

Comment: Thanks alot I got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can - possibly - make them the same if you hint postgres to not use Nested Loops:

```
SET enable_nestloop = 'off';
```

You can make it permanent by setting it to either server, role, inside function definition or server configuration:

```
ALTER DATABASE postgres
  SET enable_nestloop = 'off';
ALTER ROLE lkaminski
  SET enable_nestloop = 'off';

CREATE FUNCTION add(integer, integer) RETURNS integer
    AS 'select $1 + $2;'
    LANGUAGE SQL
    SET enable_nestloop = 'off'
    IMMUTABLE
    RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT;
```

As for why - you change search condition and planner estimates that from `tk_trip` he will get 1 row instead of 7, so it changes plan because it seems like Nested Loop will be better. Sometimes it is wrong about those and you might get slower execution time. But if you "force" it to not use Nested Loops then for different parameter it could be slower to use second plan instead of first one (with Nested Loop).

You can make planner estimates more accurate by increasing how much statistics it gathers per column. It *might* help.

```
ALTER TABLE tk_trip ALTER COLUMN route_id SET STATISTICS 1000;
```

As a side note - your `LEFT JOIN` is actually `INNER JOIN`, because you have put conditions for that table inside WHERE instead of `ON`. You should get different plan (and result) if you move them over to `ON` - assuming you wanted LEFT JOIN.

Comment: thanks @Łukasz Kamiński, it is really helpful. But I am using ON operator.
I tried using WHERE also. still give me same result. but if i remove condition DATE_PART('year', t.departure)= '2017', it give me same result